# How can I run my node.js process with a permanent sqlite database?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, docker

My Node.JS is supposed to store data with local SQLite databases. When I stop the container though, the SQLite data is lost, because it's being written on the docker path (which gets deleted when the container stops), how can I make it so the SQLite databases stay persistent?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.3

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/test
WORKDIR /usr/src/test

COPY package.json /usr/src/test
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/test

CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

I read on another question that I should use `VOLUME []` but I don't know how I can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make it so the SQLite databases stay persistent?

When you run your container, use the `docker run -v` option to mount some sort of external storage to hold the database.  It helps if the database file is in a directory that doesn't also have application source in it.

```
docker run -v $PWD/db:/usr/src/test/db ...
```

Maintaining file storage in Docker can be a little bit hairy (and this gets worse if you're ever going to look at a clustered system like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes) and you should consider using a "real" relational database in a second container.

> should [I] use `VOLUME []`

Unless you're 100% clear on what it does and why you want it, no, you should not use `VOLUME` in your Dockerfile.  It mostly only has confusing side effects.  You can mount external files or named volumes into your container as shown above without any `VOLUME` declarations.